# pip keeps pointing to python 2.7 instead of 3.7, on raspbian/ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have installed python3 on my raspberry 4, and i guess there is a native python2 as well. I must use a library that needs python3.6+, and it checks the version of pip (not pip3!) and if it finds out that it points to python2, it throws an exception. My pip command is stuck pointing to python2.7 and I would like it to point to python3 instead. I've tried many things from other answers:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

and

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force pip
```

then

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

None of the above changed the behaviour, and I still get this when i run `pip -V`:
Warning: pip is being invoked by an old script wraper...[...]

> pip 20.02 from /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python
> 2.7)

What can I do? Thanks

Comment: You should always use the `pythonX.Y -m pip` form. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why don't you use `update-alternatives`?

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip3 3
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip2 2
# the syntax is like: sudo update-alternatives --install <path> <name> <alternative> <priority>
# then you might change the default pip (which must by now be pip3) like this
sudo update-alternatives --config pip
```

one can consider this solution as an easier/cleaner alternative to symlink

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading pip won’t solve your problem, this source of the problem is the fact that you have both `python2` and `python3` on your system.

#### Solution 1 - virtual environment

(Which I recommend)

using

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

To create a virtualenv

then activate it using

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

reinstall the required dependencies if needed, and `pip` should work. Read More about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). When you'be finished working, deactivate using `deactivate`. Remember that you have to activate an environment every time

#### Solution 2 - Symlink or Copy

if you don’t want isolated environments you can symlink (Or copy over) the pip3 path to pip path so that running pip is like running pip3. Find the two paths using

```
which pip
which pip3
```

Then symlink them using

```
ln -s <pip3 path> <pip path>
```

Or copy over it using

```
cp <pip3 path> <pip path>
```

If at some point you want to reverse this (which is to keep `pip` and `pip3` you can remove the package `/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip` And install it again using `get-pip.py`

#### Solution 3 - `update-alternatives`

the [`update-alternatives`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) command might be easier than symlinking
see @erfan's answer for details

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip3 3
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip2 2
sudo update-alternatives --config pip
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `pip3` instead of `pip`. If you do want to use the `pip` command instead of `pip3`, create an alias for it in your `.bashrc` file (or `.zshrc` file if you have zsh shell). This file is located in your home directory (`/home/pi` or `~`)

Add this line to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```sh
alias pip="pip3"
```

Or use a python3 virtualenv. This is recommended for projects that you work on and won't want to install dependencies of that project globally. Simply go to your project folder and type:

```sh
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate # Command to activate venv
# and now you can use pip command instead of pip3
```

Do remember that you have to reactivate venv everytime you open a terminal